# Catching browser recording

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, browser

Is there any function that catch browser is recording or not? For example I record my pc and if i open my website then comes error that you are recording.Is it posible? for example with jquery, javascript, php, html or something else.

Comment: No, not possible. People can record with all sorts of software or hardware, and there is no universal way to detect them.

Comment: @Robin thank you very much.